stationay process, signals of different variances
I want to make sure I am understanding the meaning of a (wide-sense) stationary (WSS) process.
Say $X_t$ is a discrete WSS zero-mean process, for example white noise.
I define: $Y_t = Z  X_t$, where $Z$ is a Gaussian RV, independent of $X_t$. Is it correct that $Y_t$ is also still stationary? In this case, each signal from the process $Y_t$ will have a different variance, but the ensemble averages will still fit the definitions of WSS process? I.e.,
$E[Y_{t1}] = E[Y_{t2}]$, etc.

This question is far too much like homework. In any case, you need to show some progress towards a solution, e.g. calculating $E[Y_{t_1}]$ and $E[Y_{t_2}]$ to see if they are equal etc.

what details are missing?

"What details are missing?"  The ones that you added when you edited your question.

One missing detail don't make a question unanswerable. A good scientist is capable of discussing different case, like what if X and Z are independent, or what if X and Z are dependent, or any other details that seem relevant.
For the future and the benefit of this website, I would suggest you train thinking more like a scientist, who is open-minded and can see and discuss different options in a broad way.
Your comment about "(badly-posed) homework" felt very patronizing, unkind, and narrow-minded.

Indeed, $Y_t$​ satisfies the conditions for WSS:
a. Mean of $Y_t$​:
Since $Z$ and $X_t$​ are independent, we have:
$E[Y_t]=E[ZX_t]=E[Z]E[X_t]=0$
for any $t$.
b. Autocovariance of $Y_t$​:
$Cov(Y_t,Y_{t+\tau})=E[Y_tY_{t+\tau}]=E[Z^2X_tX_{t+\tau}]=E[Z^2]E[X_tX_{t+\tau}]=E[Z^2]⋅\gamma_{ X(\tau)}$
Here, $\gamma_{ X(\tau)}$ is the autocovariance of the process $X_t$​, which depends only on the time lag $\tau$. Since $E[Z^2]$ is constant, the autocovariance of $Y_t$ also depends only on $\tau$, satisfying the WSS condition for the autocovariance.
The reasoning doesn't change if $X_t$ is not zero-mean.
